# Select statement with column based on another column values of same table

Tags: sql, select, subquery

I need select statement like

```
select Invoice, Original Color,Product,Option Color, Result_column from table
```

where Result_column value is based on below condition

1. Available options are only 3 colors, RED, GREEN and BLUE.
2. if all Option_Colors in invoice are green then result column will be
   GREEN.
3. if all Option_Colors in invoice are blue then result column will be
   BLUE
4. if all Option_Colors in invoice are red then result column will be
   RED
5. In case of mixture of colors in Option_Colors of invoice, then
   whatever Color Original_Color column shows.

   6. In case Option_Colors is not RED, GREEN or BLUE then whatever Color
      Original_Color column shows.

[image: result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please provide a minimal reproducible example of what you have already tried. Ref. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
select Invoice, OriginalColor, OptionColor, 
 case 
   when OptionColor not in ('RED', 'BLUE', 'GREEN') then OriginalColor 
   when Result_Column > 1 then OriginalColor 
   else OptionColor end as Result_Column 
from (
   select i.Invoice, i.OriginalColor, i.OptionColor, 
   (select count(distinct OptionColor) from table ic where ic.Invoice = i.Invoice) as Result_Column  
   from table i
) temp
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of case statement, that would be easier as well.

```
select Invoice, Original_Color,Product,Option_Color, case when Option_Color not in 
('RED', 'GREEN', 'BLUE')  THEN Original_Color else Option_Color end Result_column from 
table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
with mytablecnt(Invoice, Cnt) as
(
select Invoice, count(distinct OptionColor) as Cnt
from mytable
group by Invoice
)
select t1.Invoice, t1.OriginalColor, t1.OptionColor,
    case
    when t2.Cnt = 1 then OptionColor
    when t2.Cnt != 1 then OriginalColor
    end as ResultColumn
from mytable t1
left join mytablecnt t2
on t1.Invoice = t2.Invoice
order by Invoice
```

Comment: In Invoice 1123 it shows "RED" whereas it should show "GREEN"

We need to consider all rows of every invoice for decision making
First preference is OptionColor column, if all rows has same color of red,green or blue then resultColumn is whatever optioncolor is.

But in case if all rows of any invoice has optionColor mixture of colors OR other then red,blue and green then OrignalColor Column value will be used.

note:OrignalColor Col always show same color in all rows of individual invoice which is  red, green or blue

Comment: @AliBaba Thank you for clarifying the problem. I have updated the SQL statement accordingly and the results match your sample results.